# How to interact with the omnet++ simulation via code?

Tags: omnet++

I'm about to start a project using OMNeT++, but I've not yet much experience with it.

From what I've understood, an OMNeT++ simulation is C++ code that uses a set of APIs provided by the omnet framework. What I would like to know is, is there any way to mimic, via code, the behavior of the GUI? For example, is there a way to write a C++ binary (which also contains the simulation code) and be able to control the simulation from it? Eg. the binary waits for input from the keyboard, if I write "step" it executes one step of the simulation, if I write "get state X" it outputs the state of some module X, and so on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to drive the simulation kernel in different ways. Each simulation is running in a so called 'Environment'. OMNeT++ provides *Cmdenv* (console only, non-interactive) and *Qtenv* (Qt based interactive GUI). The environment API is well defined ([cEnvir](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cEnvir.html)), so nothing stops you to implement and register your own environment. See `samples/embedding` and `samples/embedding2` for example code.